# File handle leak in windows while executing java file

Tags: memory-leaks, named-pipes, handle, filehandle

Have been observing handles creeping up in windows while running a Java executable file. Even though there is no transactions the handles are getting increased when I check the handle type count using Sys internals Handles tool the file count is too high and the path is device/NamedPipe.

I tried closing possible file openings and trying to find If there is anything to do with windows.

Comment: Try a profiler like Deleaker.